# How to add function from js file as an onclick function in ejs

Tags: javascript, ejs

I am new to ejs and am not sure how to add event handlers to components yet. This is an example that I am having trouble with.
js file:

```
printVal = function(val) {
  console.log(val);
}

router.get('/route', (req, res) => {
  res.render('temp', {user:req.user, printVal: printVal});
})
```

temp.ejs file:

```
<a href="/dashboard" class="button" onclick="printVal('<%=user.name%>')">Print</a>
```

I've searched other queries to realize that this won't work since printVal function is not recognized by clientside js code, but I also know that doing onclick="<% printVal() %>" isn't going to give me what I want since then the function will know longer await but instead console log before rendering the screen. So I am stuck as to what to do.

Comment: Define the function in a client-side JS file, not a server-side one.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes that would work but I am working with a project that involves accessing the database so I would like to do the same logic with serverside js functions. I was wondering if there was any way to do this.

Comment: No, but how are these things related? You do the database access on the server-side of course, and the rest on the client-side. (And you use an AJAX request to communicate between client and server when needed.)

Comment: I did find other responses that told to use AJAX but I haven't studied AJAX req yet, so I was trying to find a way to do this with event handlers in js. If using AJAX is the only way to acheive this in ejs then I will have to study this more.